# Need a library for creating binary Excel files from ASP.NET anyone know a good one?

Tags: .net, asp.net, excel

Preferably free if possible.

I've tried using xml / html formats but I'm running into a problem where by excel prompts the user with a security warning because the content does not match the MIME type (the sheet is downloaded on the web), no way around this it seems.

Comment: Are you sure you added the headers for content-type and content-disposition using Response.AddHeaders? Also note that the mime type (content-type) for office 2007 and higher is different than the older versions of office.

Comment: Yes, I've used the following:

Comment: Response.AddHeader( "Content-Disposition", "Attachment; filename=Report.xls" );
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

Comment: Seriously, I'm surprised this is such a difficult problem to solve without splashing out on a spread sheet gear licence or something!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following workaround for using xml: [Asp.NET Excel spreadsheet generation results in “different file format than extension error” when opening in excel, but the spreadsheet shows correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652377/asp-net-excel-spreadsheet-generation-results-in-different-file-format-than-ext/1159717#1159717)

Answer (score 0):

**[Update]**

Download the ExcelPackage library from [Codeplex](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/). This is a wrapper around the `System.IO.Packaging` which is used to create Open XML format files (docx, xlsx, pptx).

The added sample does not contain color formating, but check the samples on the site for using a template, or read the discussions on Codeplex for qa's about setting more style options per cell.

```
public void CreateExcel()
{
    FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\temp\test.xlsx");
    using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
    {
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("People");

        // Titles in Column 1
        worksheet.Cell(1, 1).Value = "Name";
        worksheet.Cell(3, 1).Value = "Tom";
        worksheet.Cell(4, 1).Value = "Henry";

        worksheet.Column(1).Width = 20; // set column 1 width                

        // Values in column 2
        worksheet.Cell(1, 2).Value = "Age";
        ExcelCell cell1 = worksheet.Cell(3, 2);                
        cell1.Value = "42"; // Age of Tom
        ExcelCell cell2 = worksheet.Cell(4, 2);
        cell2.Value = "19"; // Age of Henry

        string calcStartAddress = cell1.CellAddress;
        string calcEndAddress = cell2.CellAddress;

        worksheet.Cell(5, 2).Formula = string.Format("SUM({0}:{1})",calcStartAddress, calcEndAddress);
        worksheet.Cell(6, 2).Formula = string.Format("AVERAGE({0}:{1})", calcStartAddress, calcEndAddress);
        xlPackage.Save();
    }
}
```

---

**[Original answer]**

You can use ADO.Net.

Download [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=c06b8369-60dd-4b64-a44b-84b371ede16d) and check out [this post](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/05/26/2973.aspx) on how to read/write Excel files with ADO.Net.

Just change your connection string to

`Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source=pathtoyourfile; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;`

Using v12 and the ACE.OLEDB connection instead of Jet.OLEDB.

Comment: According to the first link Extended Properties should be set to "Excel 14.0"

Comment: I know, but I've had trouble with this, and 12 seems to work. 12 is the version number for Office 2007, while 14 is for 2010. But the file formats haven't changed between 2007 and 2010.

Comment: I need a bit more formatting control than this appears to offer unfortunatley.

Comment: Added link and code sample for using ExcelPackage. And you should be able to style it like you want with the use of templates or modify the code a bit like mentioned in the discussion forum.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question I'm not sure if you need support for older 2003 (.xls) version, but I've recently used the [`ExcelPackage`](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/) library from codeplex to create xlsx OOXML and it worked great for my needs.