# A dialog box comes when I try to open excel file with .xls as extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel

I am using the below code for export the data to excel sheet.

```
    private void ExportToExcel(string fileName)
    {
        fileName = "MyXML.xls";

        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
        System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
        rptLinks.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
        Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

Everything is working fine but when I try to open the excel file **MyXML.xls** by double clicking, a popup/dialog box open with the below message :

"The file you are trying to open , **MyXML.xls** is in different format than specified by the file extension. " etc..

Can we make some changes in code so that no popup/dialog should come?

Comment: Possible dup of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652377/excel-spreadsheet-generation-results-in-different-file-format-than-extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps

http://devblog.grinn.net/2008/06/file-you-are-trying-to-open-is-in.html

Answer (score 2):

change  Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls"; to  Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940045/how-to-suppress-the-file-corrupt-warning-at-excel-download#answer-940082