# Exporting Excel file from ASP returns "different file format than extension error”

Tags: excel, asp-classic

I have read a lot about this subject ( [Excel spreadsheet generation results in "different file format than extension error" when opening in excel 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652377/excel-spreadsheet-generation-results-in-different-file-format-than-extension) and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/03/11/excel-2007-extension-warning.aspx) and from my understanding, there is not a server-side solution to this problem. 
The thing is the majority of the posts regarding this subject all have more than 2 years now.

Has there been any development regarding the export of .xls and .xlsx files from a web page? Is the only solution to use another format like .csv?

This is the code I currently have, and aside the Excel message, it works without any problem

```
    <%

    Dim objExXML
    Dim objExXSL

    set objExXML = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    objExXML.async = false
    objExXML.loadxml(session("variable"))

    set objExXSL = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    objExXSL.async = false
    objExXSL.load(Server.MapPath("file_test.xsl"))


    Dim excelStr
    excelStr = objExXML.transformNode(objExXSL)

    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    Response.AddHeader "content-disposition", "Attachment; filename=file.xlsx"
    Response.Write excelStr

    %>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc

Comment: If I add the contenttype application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet the result is the same.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there have been any developments, especially in the Classic ASP world. Your best bet is still one of the following:

- Output your report in a different format, such as CSV or Excel XML, and set `Response.ContentType` to the appropriate MIME type

or

- Educate your users to let them know to expect the warning